# Can't play ogg and flac

Tags: qt, ogg, flac

Qt 5.0.1 QMediaPlayer on 32 bit Windows XP can only play MP3 and WAV files. How can I extend it to play OGG and FLAC files too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt's multimedia module uses the platform codecs. If you don't have codecs installed for Vorbis (it's not called Ogg; that's just the container format) and FLAC, then you won't be able to play those formats.

You can find the needed codecs here:

http://www.xiph.org/dshow

Comment: Can I deploy needed codecs with my application? That user don't have to install

Comment: @Dibo I don't know. Check the docs whether the codecs have a silent install option. You can also ask about it on the Vorbis mailing list (http://lists.xiph.org/mailman/listinfo/vorbis).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with QMediaPlayer. I tried in a fresh VM: with the codecs installed, it becomes possible to play the ogg files with Windows Media Player, but they still don't play with Qt's QMediaPlayer. I tested against Qt 5.15, Windows and Linux. It works okay with Linux. Doesn't play a sound on Windows, nor output anything to the console.